# Finding the most general unifier in Haskell using Data.Comp.Unification (beginner question)

Tags: haskell, type-inference, lambda-calculus, unification, type-theory

I have the following structure in haskell, which implements some machinery for printing and calls the unifier. I get the following error from main:

```
0 =/= int
```

It seems to think that 0 is a number rather than a variable. Below is the full implementation.

```
 data CType 
      = CVar Int 
      | CArr CType CType
      | CInt
      | CBool
      deriving (Eq, Data)

data Constraint 
  = Equality CType CType
    deriving (Eq, Data)
```

I have some base types (int and bool), an arrow type, and type variables. 
Then I am running some algorithms that generate equality constraints which are represented in the way above.

My goal is that given a list of constraints, I want to find the most general unifier.

I came across this library: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata-0.1/docs/Data-Comp-Unification.html

Since I am new to Haskell, I can't immediately figure out if I can directly apply it. Could I use this library or am I recommended to write the unifier from scratch?

**UPDATE**

I am currently making the following changes to the code, but am getting a unification error for the equation

> f=g

```
module SolveEq where
import Data.Data
import Data.Void
import Data.List as List
import Data.Map as Map
import Data.Set as Set
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Data.Maybe (isJust)
import Control.Monad
import TypeCheck
import Data.Comp.Variables
import Data.Comp.Unification
import Data.Comp.Term
import Data.Comp.Derive
import Constraint
import Lang

data CTypeF a 
    = CVarF Int 
    | CArrF a a
    | CIntF
    | CBoolF
    deriving (Data, Functor, Foldable, Traversable, Show, Eq)

$(makeShowF ''CTypeF)


example :: String
example = showF (CIntF :: CTypeF String)

instance HasVars CTypeF Int where
isVar (CVarF x) = Just x
isVar (CArrF x y) = Nothing
isVar CIntF = Nothing
isVar CBoolF = Nothing

type CType_ = Term CTypeF

f :: CType_
f = Term (CVarF 0)

g :: CType_
g = Term CIntF


unravel :: CType_ -> CType
unravel a = 
    case unTerm a of 
        CVarF i -> CVar i
        CArrF a b -> CArr (unravel a) (unravel b)
        CIntF -> CInt
        CBoolF -> CBool

getUnify :: Either (UnifError CTypeF Int) (Subst CTypeF Int)
getUnify = unify [(f,g)]

main = case getUnify of
  Left (FailedOccursCheck v term)     -> putStrLn ("failed occurs check " ++ show v ++ ": " ++ (show $ unravel term))
  Left (HeadSymbolMismatch t1 t2)     -> putStrLn ("head symbol mismatch " ++ show (unravel t1)  ++ " =/= " ++ (show $ unravel t2))
  Left (UnifError str)     -> putStrLn str
  Right (subst :: Subst CTypeF Int) -> print (fmap unravel subst)
```

The issue is in `unify [(f,g)]` which I would have expected to map 0 to Int. But it seems to not see that 0 is a variable. Is there something wrong with my isVar possibly?

Note: I am running with compdata-0.12

Comment: Unrelated note: I personally wouldn't call a type of my own `Constraint` due to possible confusion with [the `Constraint` kind built in to GHC](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.5/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#the-constraint-kind)

Comment: Oh no! okay I'll change it. Thank you!

Comment: Aha, you need to indent the definition of `isVar` inside your `HasVars` instance. That should fix it.

Comment: omg it works! finally :) Thank you so so much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use that library, but you'll have to make a minor change to your data structure. Specifically, you'll have to rewrite it as a signature functor instead of a recursive data type.

Here's what that means: your `CType` type is recursive because it contains other instances of `CType` within one of its constructors (`CArr`). Rewriting a recursive data type as a signature means making a data type that takes a type parameter, and using that type parameter everywhere you'd use recursion instead. Like this:

```
 data CTypeF a 
      = CVar Int 
      | CArr a a
      | CInt
      | CBool
      deriving (Eq, Data)
```

Now, in your program, where you previously passed around `CType`s, you'll need to work with something a little more complicated than just `CTypeF`. Your new `CType`-equivalent needs to apply `CTypeF` circularly, to itself. Fortunately, [`Term`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata-0.1/docs/Data-Comp-Term.html#t:Term) does this for you, so import `Data.Comp.Term` and replace all your `CType`s with `Term CTypeF`s. (You can, of course, always alias `type CType = Term CTypeF` to save some typing; just be aware that `Term CTypeF` is not literally the same as your original `CType`; you'll need to add some `Term` constructors to places that produce and consume `CType`s.)

Finally, in order to use the unification machinery in `compdata`, you'll need an instance of [`HasVars`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata-0.1/docs/Data-Comp-Variables.html#t:HasVars) for `CTypeF` that identifies your `CVar` constructor as a variable. You'll also need to make `CTypeF` both a `Functor` and `Foldable`, but if you enable the [`DeriveFunctor`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-DeriveFunctor) and [`DeriveFoldable`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-DeriveFoldable) language features, GHC can do this for you—it's a strictly mechanical process.

---

When running `unify`, you need to make sure you're doing it in a context where the error monad `m` and the variable type `v` are unambiguous. There are many ways to do this, but for the sake of example, let's say that we're using the simplest error monad `Either e` as our `m`, and of course you'll want `v` to be `Int`. So you might write:

```
f = Term (CVar 2)
g = Term CInt

-- By matching against Left and Right, we're letting GHC know that unify
-- should return an Either; this disambiguates `m`
main = case unify [(f, g)] of
  Left _      -> print "did not unify"
  Right subst -> doMoreWork subst

-- The Int here disambiguates `v`
doMoreWork :: Subst CTypeF Int -> IO ()
doMoreWork subst = undefined -- fill in the blank!
```

Comment: Everything works right now. Just one small thing. Currently I want to test the unify function from this package, and I declare f = (Term (CVarF 2)) and g = (Term CIntF)
and t = (f,g). The signature of unify is very confusing to me. I was wondering if you can show a simple function that just calls unify on t?

Comment: It should just be `unify [t]`... what happens when you try that?

Comment: I get: • Ambiguous type variables ‘v0’, ‘m0’ arising from a use of ‘unify’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Control.Monad.Error.Class.MonadError
                                  (UnifError CTypeF v0) m0)’ from being solved.  so I assume I must type it, but the type signature is very strange so I am lost on what that should be

Comment: Ah, okay! That means you're calling `unify` correctly, as far as its signature is concerned, but whatever it is that you're doing with the result of `unify` is too unconstrained. You need to give GHC more information about what you expect from `unify`, one way or another. See edited answer.

Comment: For some reason, unifying [t] gives the wrong answer. It results in "head symbol mismatch 2 =/= int". i implemented everything mentioned above. Was I supposed to implement anything else? I would have expected the solver to map 2 to int.

Comment: I would too. Can you update your question with an MCVE? You can't be missing any required instances, or your program wouldn't compile; it must be that something was written incorrectly. (I suspect the `HasVars` instance, but I'd need your code to be sure.)

Comment: Oh, and be sure to include which versions of libraries you're using; it looks like `compdata`'s API has changed between the 0.1 version you linked and the most recent 0.12 version.

Comment: Yes, definitely. Updating now!